# Get Start Date and End date for certain month count

Tags: c#, datetime

```
int months = applicationLookBack.LookBackPeriod; //In Months

public class DateRange 
{
     public virtual DateTime? Startdate { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime? Enddate { get; set; }
}
```

What will be the best way to calculate and fill this DateRange with
the month count?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: suppose that i get month count of 3 than the start date will be 1 jan 2015  and end date will be 31 mar 2015

Comment: Also the one who marked this question negative please come forward and explain why!

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMonths(months)` Is to get time span. Also, if you don't know StartDate or EndDate you cannot calculate anything. You need to know at least one of them to get value.

Comment: How do you determine the start date by a period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int months = 14;
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(currentYear, 1, 1);
    DateTime lastDate = firstDate.AddMonths(months - 1);

    var lastMonthDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(lastDate.Year, lastDate.Month);
    lastDate = lastDate.AddDays(lastMonthDays - 1);
```

Comment: @SachinPrasad So you wanted us to psychically figure out that you wanted the start date to be the first day of the current year, and the last day to be `n` months later than this, minus one day?